# partial differentiation with log function.

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Can someone please help as I am stuck,

I need to show that

$$\phi=\frac{k}{2\pi}\log(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1/2}$$

satisfies Laplaces equation, however I cannot seem to differentiate this function. Note $k$ is a constant.

How do I go about partially differentiating

$$\log(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})$$

I was thinking, using chain rule, just call

$$\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=r$$

so $$\frac{1}{r}\log r+\log r$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset your work. As it stands now, the line pi = k/2pi(log...) is impossible to understand.

Comment: thank you , i have edited it now, hope its more understandable?

Comment: Sure, now I can read it. The differential of $\log x^{2}$ is $2x/x^{2}$ so the partial differential of $\log(x^{2} + y^{2})$ with respect to $x$ is

$$\frac{2x}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$

What do you think will happen if we replace $(x^{2} + y^{2})$ with $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you would immediately use $log(\sqrt{x^2+ y^2})= \frac{1}{2}log(x^2+ y^2)$.  That will simplify your problem.

Comment: I thought of that, but  wasn't sure if am  'allowed' to bring the 1/2 down like that. ?